# MFC button not appearing as topmost

Tags: windows, mfc

I have a vector of buttons which I want to appear in two dialogs. Some in my current window, and one in the parent of the current window. And I want them to appear as topmost.

So, for the current window, it works OK.
For the parent window, I set the parent, the button is being correctly positioned, but it is appearing behind another button.

I am already setting SWP_NOZORDER:

```
std::vector<CGdipButtonEx*> m_trashIcons;
...
m_trashButtons[i]->SetWindowPos(nullptr,x,y,25,25,SWP_NOZORDER );
```

Comment: I see it as badly designed UI! Why overlap controls?

Comment: I was pre-requisite for the buttons to have trash icons that could be cllicked and delete the buttons on UI.

Answer (score 0):

To set a button to appear above other buttons you need to pass `HWND_TOP` as the first parameter, `hwndInsertAfter`.

```
m_trashButtons[i]->SetWindowPos(HWND_TOP,x,y,25,25,SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

Do not pas `SWP_NOZORDER`. Z-order is the order in which the windows are on top of each other (z-axis). That is the thing you DO want to set, so saying "no z-order please" is exactly and precisely the wrong thing to do.

As per the documentation:

> SWP_NOZORDER 0x0004 
>   Retains the current Z order (ignores the hWndInsertAfter parameter).

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Actually I've already tried using &CWnd::wndTop as first argument (with HWND_TOP didnt compiled). I've made different combinations, with SWP_SHOWWINDOW that you suggested... but nothing worked till now :(

Comment: Yes... I've tried using it or not.. combining with different optins of hWndInsertAfter parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The windows are hierarchical. If you have two dialogs that both have controls on them, all of the controls in the upper dialog will appear over the controls in the lower dialog, even if the controls in the lower dialog are marked topmost and the ones in the upper dialog aren't.

Comment: Well, I am setting the parent of the other window. Anyway, i tried now to make everything on the first dialog and problem persists.. =[